# Why are some foods haram for Muslims?

Tags: halal-haram, food, animals, meat

For a research project I would like to know why Muslims aren't supposed to eat:

1. animals that have died of natural causes, by accident, or due to other animals
2. carnivorous animals with fangs/birds of prey
3. pigs
4. amphibians and reptiles
5. donkeys and horses
6. pets
7. domestic animals
8. pests

Thank you for any contribute, it is very much appreciated :)